# How to add a column of simple moving average of another column to a Julia data frame

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a Julia data frame where one column is called 'close' and I want to add another column to the data frame called 'sma' which is a simple moving average of 'close'.  Thanks to anyone who can help!

I noticed a problem in the code amrod.  It doesn't account for the first length of SMA that doesn't have enough previous data points for a good SMA and also gives double the SMA that is asked for.  I changed it to input zeros up to that point, I also changed the variable names when I was figuring out how it works.

```
function makeSMA(data, SMA)
    len = length(data)
    y = Vector{Float64}(len)
    for i in 1:SMA-1
        y[i] = NaN
    end
    for i in SMA:len
        y[i] = mean(data[i-(SMA-1):i])
    end
    return y
end
```

Comment: you can change the way the function handles these extreme points by modifying `hi` and `lo`.

Comment: By 'double the SMA asked for', I mean if you ask for an SMA of 8 it gives you an SMA of 16.  lo stays at 1 for the first 8 steps, while hi is going from 8-16.

Comment: and what you are calling `SMA` that doubles is in fact the (half-) window (hence `wind`) over where to calculate the mean, the SMA is the function or the series you get afterwards. So, a window of 4, takes values from `i-4` to `i+4`. I think this approach is better since you don't have to worry about non-integer indices.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, I'm using this for a backwards looking SMA, I guess that's where we are seeing it differently.

Comment: OK then. By the way, I think a better way of handling these "low-order MA" is to assign them to be `NaN`.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to NaN.  I've been trying to figure out Julia for a few days now and now that I have a hold on how to manipulate arrays thanks to your snippet I'm off to a good start finally!  Thank you amrods!

Comment: Another option (and the preferred IMO) is to return a shorter vector with the first or last elements removed (when their window is partial). NaNs complicate calculation and it is important to keep the process of data production uniform in order to avoid adding bias in later stages.

Comment: truly, it's just that @puzzler wanted to concatenate the vectors after the operation.

Comment: yeah, concatenation with original series requires either NAs or chopping the original time-series. For the former, using the stabilizing `Nullable` type is better than `NaN` (but slower). For the latter (chopping), we can return a vector of indices which are good. Again, IMO the latter is preferable. The result would look: `(ma,inds) = movingaverage(v,wind); [v[inds] ma]`. Again, the variations are many.

Comment: @user3580870 Your worry about using `NaN` is that those values can "poison" some operation down the road? I find it a bit weird that you have to wrap every value of the resulting vector in a `Nullable` to deal with this.

Comment: Nullables are hard to forget. NaNs can slip quietly in calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this:

```
function ma{T <: Real}(x::Vector{T}, wind::Int)
    len = length(x)
    y = Vector{Float64}(len)
    for i in 1:len
        lo = max(1, i - wind)
        hi = min(len, i + wind)
        y[i] = mean(x[lo:hi])
    end
    return y
end

x = collect(1:100)
y = ma(x, 4)
```

then you can `hcat(x, y)`.

EDIT:
If you want a backwards-looking MA you can use something like

```
function ma{T <: Real}(x::Vector{T}, wind::Int)
    len = length(x)
    y = Vector{Float64}(len)
    for i in 1:len
        if i < wind
            y[i] = NaN
        else
            y[i] = mean(x[i - wind + 1:i])
        end
    end
    return y
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! :)  I just had to remove the 'vector' specification.

Comment: @puzzler yeah, probably a more general approach is to supply an nx1 or 1xn `Array`.

Comment: In the second version, the average is taken over a `wind`+1 number of elements. It may be more intuitive to make `wind` correspond to the number of elements.

Comment: just fixed it to make wind correspond to the number of elements taken in the MA